# Fortran type variables are zero when accessed with the % operator

Tags: types, fortran

I'm trying to access elements of a data type with the % operator, but the result is zero.  I have some example code below.

The line `print*, t%tsum` always prints out zero.  However when I print tsum within the subroutine it's what it should be.

```
MODULE statistics

PUBLIC :: TimeMarker , start , finish , avgTime , begin , end_ , tsum ,  counts 

TYPE TimeMarker
  REAL*8 :: begin , end_ , tsum 
  INTEGER :: counts = 0
    CONTAINS
            PROCEDURE :: start => start_time
            PROCEDURE :: finish => finish_time
            PROCEDURE :: avgTime => averageTime
END TYPE TimeMarker


CONTAINS


        SUBROUTINE start_time(this)
        CLASS(timeMarker) , INTENT(INOUT) :: this
        CALL CPU_TIME(begin)
            END SUBROUTINE start_time      

            SUBROUTINE finish_time(this)
        CLASS(timeMarker) , INTENT(INOUT) :: this
        CALL CPU_TIME(end_)
        tsum = tsum + end_ - begin
        counts = counts + 1
            END SUBROUTINE finish_time          

            SUBROUTINE averageTime(this)
        CLASS(timeMarker) , INTENT(INOUT) :: this
        WRITE(*,*) "Average time : " , tsum/counts
            END SUBROUTINE averageTime   


END MODULE statistics



program test
  use statistics
  implicit none
  type(TimeMarker) :: t
  integer :: n , m
  real*8 :: a

  do m=1,50    
    call t%start
    do n=1,20000000
      a = sqrt(a)
    end do  

    print*, t%tsum

  end do
  call t%avgTime


end program test
```

Comment: Real*8 is not part of Fortran and as such is potentially not portable. I strongly suggest you learn about the Fortran kind mechanism and how to use it. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter or look at a good book such as Metcalf, Reid and Cohen

Comment: Always use IMPLICIT NONE.

Answer (score 3):

Within the type bound procedures, components of the passed object are still referenced using the syntax `argument_name % component_name`.  There is no implicit "this" variable for the passed object, as you might find in other languages.  You've used `this` as the name of the passed argument - so for example the begin component must be referenced as `this % begin`, not just `begin`.

In the scope of the module, implicit typing is in effect - the module does not have an IMPLICIT NONE statement.  Consequently, the variables that you are manipulating in your type bound procedures are implicitly declared module variables, which means the compiler reports no errors.

There are other logic errors in the example code, that will need to be dealt with once the component references have been fixed.

(`%` is not an operator in Fortran, it is just part of the syntax.)